# Warning and info provider control in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

Is there something like info provider and warning provider in Windows form. Like we have [error provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have found some solutions online, where images in background are used and similar tricks to make error provider to look like other two. Is there some better way?

Comment: The accepted answer shows how to set the icon. And if you would like to use it with a `DataSource` [here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo) is an example I recently created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the icon, if that's your concern.  Consider the following, where `WarningPNG16x` is a PNG image object:

```
errorProvider1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(WarningPNG16x.GetHicon());
```

Of course, if you have an `Icon` already, just assign it.

As LarsTech pointed out, you could use the `SystemIcon` versions, as well:

```
errorProvider1.Icon = SystemIcons.Warning;
```

Comment: I think you can just use SystemIcons, too.

Comment: @LarsTech Indeed, good point.  Copied this from our app, where we have our own art for everything.

Comment: It is really simple solution. Thanks.  Is there a way to resize system icon? It looks bigger then original error provider.

Comment: It would not be easy.  You'd have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but still just for closure...
I had a similar issue and needed both an error- & warning- provider.
I used this [IconEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695976/resize-system-icon-in-c-sharp) (accepted answer by Hans Passant)to grab the correctly sized windows icons.

usage:

```
wrnProvider.Icon = new IconEx(IconEx.SystemIcons.Warning, SystemInformation.SmallIconSize).Icon;
```