# How to add a warning sign to CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I need the user to be aware of some important but not essential fields.
In order to do so I must add warning signs next to the controls.
The problem is that there is a variety of controls in the form.

Some are text box (successfully added a warning icon)
Some are checkbox (successfully added a warning icon)
Some are calcedit ((succesfully added a warning icon)

But some like the checkedlistbox I can't seem to find a way to add a warning icon.

I've tried a number of things used for the other controllers.
i.e dxerrorprovider and errorimageoption (a property that cannot be found on the control of interest)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680619/warning-and-info-provider-control-in-win-forms

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If you want to add a warning icon if a user did not select a value, use [DXValidationProvider](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.DXValidationProvider) and configure it as shown below:

[image: DXValidationProvider configuration]